# Why does disconnectedness necessarily require that both partitions be open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

One definition of a connected set is that it cannot be represented as a partition of subsets $\{A,B\}$ where their union is the set, they are disjoint and they are both open.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider a circle center $(0,-2)$, radius $1$. Let it be $A\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider a circle center $(0,2)$ radius $1$ and denote this one as $B\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the metric space $X=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

We have that $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ and $X=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$.

So now I am confused because it seems intuitively that $X$ is disconnected but I also cannot see how $\overline{A}$ is open in $X$?? Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean $A\in\mathbb R^2$ or do you mean $A\subseteq R^2$?

Comment: An equivalent (but perhaps more intuitive) definition is that $X$ is disconnected with $X = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and *closed*.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both open in $X$, then they are also both closed in $X$. This is a consequence of their disjointness and the fact that they mutually exhaust $X$, since then $A=X\setminus B$ and $B=X\setminus A$ are the complements of sets open in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

In $X$, you have that $\overline{A}=X\setminus\overline{B}$, and since $\overline B$ is a closed set, $A$ is a compliment of a closed set and therefore open.

---

Or, if you want a metric space explanation, you can also prove directly that $A$ is open. Take any $x\in A$. Now, set $\epsilon = 1$. Then, the set

$$B = \{y\in X| d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$$

is an open ball in $X$, and it is also true that $B\subseteq A$, which means that $A$ is a union of open balls, and therefore open.

---

What's more, $A$ is also **an open ball** in $X$, because

$$A=\{y\in X| d(x,(-3,0)) < 3\}$$

Open balls are, of course, open by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your set $X$ is a subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$, and has inherited from ${\mathbb R}^2$ the so-called *relative topology*. This means that a set $U\subset X$ is open iff there is an open set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ such that $U=\Omega \cap X$.

Since $\bar A=X\cap D_{3/2}(0,-2)$, and the disk $D_{3/2}(0,-2)$ is open in ${\mathbb R}^2$ it follows that $\bar A$ is open in $X$. Similarly for $\bar B$. As $\bar A\cap\bar B=\emptyset$ we can conclude that $X$ is not connected.